# React-Native: Event handling by a single event handler method

Tags: react-native

Here is multiple button, I want to handle event using single method and different action will be performed on different button call

Here is my code

```
 <Grid style={styleKeybaord.grid}>

                   <Row>
                   <Col style={styleKeybaord.column}>
                   <TouchableOpacity ref = '1' onPress = {this.abc}>
                   <Text style={styleKeybaord.text}>{STRINGS.t('keybord_1')}</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity>
                   </Col>

                   <Col style={styleKeybaord.column}>
                   <TouchableOpacity ref = '2' onPress = {this.abc}>
                   <Text style={styleKeybaord.text}>{STRINGS.t('keybord_2')}</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity>
                   </Col>

                   <Col style={styleKeybaord.column}>
                   <TouchableOpacity ref = '3' onPress = {this.abc}>
                   <Text style={styleKeybaord.text}>{STRINGS.t('keybord_3')}</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity>
                   </Col>
                   </Row>
</Grid>

abc(v){

    //  Alert.alert("hhjfgdfu"+v.attr('ref'));
    }
```

Currently, this code is not working, please provide me  solution

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your function to pass directly the argument, like this.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.abc(1)}>
```

Then in your function you receive directly the ref value.

```
abc(ref){

  Alert.alert("hhjfgdfu"+ref);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,It is the solution that i was looking for.